# Correcting silicon between plasterboard

Tags: drywall, plaster, silicone

I had a contractor come in to build an internal wall, and without me agreeing to it, he used silicone between the drywall panels.  The issue is that there is a clear line down the wall where the panels were joined, and the contractor is saying that there is nothing that can be done to correct them, because there is silicone, but I don't quite believe him.

How would I go about correcting the situation so that the joint between the drywall panels is no longer visible, given that there is some silicone between them?

The wall essentially looks like the following image, only a layer of paint has been applied to the drywall.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what happened.  Was the wall taped and mudded (and the silicone showed up through the paint) or was it painted without the drywall being finished?  Pictures of the actual wall in question might help.

Comment: If this guy used silicone to finish the joints, he is a clown and should be tossed out. If the silicone is not smeared over the face of the drywall, it can be cut out with a razor knife, then have the wall finished properly with tape and drywall mud.

Comment: Also, as an extremely last result, cover his work with 3/8 drywall. More sound-proofing and insulating qualities.

Comment: He seems to have used silicon between the boards, but it isn't showing at all.  He then painted over everything with a water-based latex paint -including the silicone.

Comment: After reading the comments below - it sounds more like he (the contractor) doesn't know how to tape, and is just blowing smoke up your rear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, although difficult, can be solved. If the silicone has squeezed out from the drywall joint it needs to be cut. With a utility knife slice away all dried silicone that is above the surface of the drywall. The lower the better. Don't be overly concerned about damaging the drywall panels; don't butcher them, but don't preform surgery either. After the silicone is removed spackle and tape as usual. BTW I see screw heads in the photo, I'm guessing he used them until the silicone dried? FYI: it is not uncommon to use an adhesive to mechanically secure gypsum panels in place, but to be sure I've never come across silicone as the adhesive! Question: Is the contractor refusing to tape and spackle his drywall installation?

Comment: Yes, he is refusing to tape and spackle the drywall installation, saying it isn't possible because he used silicone.

Comment: +1 -- any competent individual should be able to cut away any squeeze-out and then tape.

Comment: Agreed with Aloysius. And I can empathize with your situation. I've had to deal with employees that wouldn't honor or guarantee their work. If the situation is at an impasse ,let it go. It's the installer of the drywall that is going to lose in the end. If he has any intelligence at all he will realize he not only did his work incorrectly, but (more importantly) he left a dissatisfied customer (now his reputation will suffer). This may be the perfect opportunity to add "taping and spackling" to your DIY resume.